# DC can't address correct DNS to workstations

Tags: dns, ip

Domain Controller has an IP of 192.168.0.10

Gateway is 192.168.0.1

A an old Linksys Router WRT120 was temporarily given an IP address of 192.168.0.120, and a default gateway of 192.168.0.1 it was causing interference. It was disconnected at the end of yesterday to resolve internet issues. (Resolved).

Now, the DNS on wired and wireless devices are pulling a DNS of 192.168.0.120 – This IP is not showing up anywhere on network scans, routing devices, etc. Basically this location is pulling the DNS incorrectly.

Some of the IPs of the Windows workstations and printers have defaulted their IPs to 169.254.74.47 (non-existent).

So far, with most of the devices in the building, we have to manually set the Network adapter with the following information *for them to properly connect to the network*.

```
 IP:192.168.0.### (Where ### = free/available IP that is not currently being used)
 Subnet: 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

 Primary DNS: 192.168.0.10
```

Where does this 192.168.0.120 seem to be pulling from if it does not exist?!

Thank you much in advance.

Comment: "an old Linksys Router WRT120 was temporarily given an IP address of 192.168.0.120" Did it have DHCP enabled? Perhaps the clients pulled the DNS of .120 from it via DHCP?  Are you using DHCP to give the clients IPs now?  If so, do you have a the proper gateway and DNS setting set to be distributed by the current DHCP server?

Comment: "169.254.x.x" are automatic addresses, which tells me you have the client set to use DHCP, but it's not getting a response from a DHCP server.

Comment: I'd suggest installing wireshark on one of the workstations that's having a problem and start sniffing the traffic. You obviously have a rouge DHCP host, or rather, your windows PC's are attempting to the incorrect host and then not obtaining a lease and defaulting to the 169.254.x.x addresses. 

HKLM/CCS/Services/TCP/Parameters is where DHCP information is held. 

https://wiki.wireshark.org/DHCP is how to test for DHCP inside of Wireshark.

Comment: I would clean the slate with `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /renew`

Comment: [SOLVED] - The **DHCP Server** service on our Windows 2003 Domain Controller did not automatically restart when the server rebooted the night before. The service needed to be manually turned on in Services. Also, I noticed that under DHCP -> [SERVER] -> Scope -> Address Pool, 192.168.0.120 was added the 'excluded' list. I am wondering if that is why the router had become the default DHCP server. _Lesson learned: Repeat necessary steps in the troubleshooting process, even if it is reported that it has already been checked._

Answer (score 1):

You can't find 192.168.0.120 on the network because that's the ip address that was assigned to the Linksys router, and you took that off of the network.

If the DHCP server that assigned the client ip address is shut down (the Linksys router in this case), a Windows DHCP client will continue using the ip address configuration that it received from the originating DHCP server and will attempt to communicate with the originating DHCP server (via unicast) throughout the renewal phase (T1) until it reaches the rebinding phase (T2), at which point it will try to contact any DHCP server (via broadcast). If the client is rebooted and it can't communicate with the originating DHCP server and it also can't communicate with any other DHCP server then the client should release it's allocated ip address, hence the APIPA addresses you're seeing.

It sounds like the Linksys router was acting as a DHCP server and assigning itself to the clients for DNS. You need to run `ipconfig/release` and `ipconfig/renew` on the clients to force them to "associate" with another DHCP server, which you need to have set up and configured to serve those clients.

If the clients are getting an APIPA address then it sounds like you don't have another DHCP server on the network, so you'll need to set one up.